Unable to start Postgres Services with pg_ctl start
The database was up and running before I stopped it.
I have stopped the database services with the pg_ctl stop command.
But when I try to start the database services with pg_ctl start, the command its showing an error.
I have not done any changes after the database was stopped.
-bash-4.2$ pg_ctl start
waiting for server to start....edb-postgres: superuser_reserved_connections (3) must be less than max_connections (1)
stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.

-bash-4.2$ cat edb-2024-05-14_000000.log
2024-05-14 09:47:22 CEST FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2024-05-14 09:47:22 CEST LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 73602) exited with exit code 1
2024-05-14 09:47:22 CEST LOG:  background worker "dbms_aq launcher" (PID 73601) exited with exit code 1
2024-05-14 09:47:22 CEST LOG:  shutting down
2024-05-14 09:47:23 CEST LOG:  database system is shut down
2024-05-14 09:47:23 CEST LOG:  database system is shut down

I am not sure what the issue is.

It looks like someone edited the postgresql.conf file to booby trap it by lowering max_connections to a bad value.  The stop worked as it doesn't try to validate the settings, but the start won't work until you fix it.

You have to edit postgresql.conf and change max_connections to a greater value.  Then you can start the PostgreSQL server again.
